# Помогите добавить куки из моего стандартного Хрома в chromedriver selinium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Не пинайте больно, я учусь))) Нужно добавить куки из обычного хрома, чтобы при открытия хром драйвера, уже должен войти в учётку и с правильным городом. Не знаю как это сделать, я так понял нужно через chrome_options, но точно не знаю как и куда влепить это(

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
import chromedriver_binary
wd = wd.Chrome()
wd.implicitly_wait(5)
wd.get("тут сайт")
add_to_cart_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button')
add_to_cart_button.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Каждый раз, когда Selenium открывает браузер (Chrome / Firefox / IE), он открывает каноническую форму этого браузера. Используйте объект ChromeOptions для передачи аргументов командной строки Chrome.

Выбрать свой профиль

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile")
```

Подробнее о возможностях драйвера Chrome:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Дополнительные сведения о параметре командной строки user-data-dir для Chrome:
https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

Так же вы можете использовать [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pickle.html) чтобы записать cookie и после использовать их:

```
def save_cookie(driver, path):
    with open(path, 'wb') as filehandler:
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), filehandler)

def load_cookie(driver, path):
     with open(path, 'rb') as cookiesfile:
         cookies = pickle.load(cookiesfile)
         for cookie in cookies:
             driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

UPD:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
import chromedriver_binary

chrome_options = wd.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile")
driver = wd.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("тут сайт")
add_to_cart_button = driver .find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button')
add_to_cart_button.click()
```

Comment: Извините, но у меня не получается применить этот код  
`from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile")`
Можете показать на примере моего кода как его использовать?

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте